# Expectation of sample variance $E(s^2)=\sigma^2$

Tags: estimators

Let

$$s^2=\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_t^2\right)-n \bar y^2}{n-1}$$

be an estimator of $\sigma^2$. Let

$$E(yAy^T)=Tr(A\Sigma)+\mu^TA\mu$$

be an identity, where $y$ is a random vector, $A$ is a suitable matrix, and $\Sigma$ is a matrix covariance of $y$.

How can be proved $E(s^2)=\sigma^2$ using the above identity?

Comment: Can you write $s^2$ as a quadratic form in $y$?

Comment: $s^2=y^Ty-n(1/ny^Tj)(1/ny^Tj)^T$ where $j$ is a $nx1$  1's vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving this result depends on the matrices $A$ and $\Sigma$.  Usually (but not always) an estimator of the variance will use a quadratic form where $A \mu = 0$ for a vector of fixed values $\mu$, so in that case the second term will be zero and $\mathbb{E}(yAy^\text{T}) = \text{tr}(A \Sigma)$.  If you have a look at the form of $A$ that emerges from your estimator formula you will see that it is proportionate to the [centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix), and it has this property.  It then remains only to derive the matrix $A \Sigma$ and show that its trace is equal to the variance parameter.  To do all this you're going to have to specify $\Sigma$, and then crunch the algebra in the formula.